# Full width navigation inside container

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm fairly new to HTML and I'm trying to recreate this wireframe example for a school assignment:
[image: Wireframe]

This is the code I wrote in order to get the result I'm aiming for:

```css
/* Reset */
a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    font: 1.6rem Arial;
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Container */
#container {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 3rem;
    max-width: 96rem;
}

/* Header */
header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2.5rem;
    background: lightgrey;
}
header > .logo {
    /* Style */
    width: 12.5rem;
    height: 12.5rem;
    background: grey;
    
    /* Flex */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
header > nav ul li {
    width: 24%;
    display: inline-block;
}
header > nav ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
header > nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>CSS Grid In Production</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="container">
    <header>
    
      <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
      
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      
    </header>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use the solutions other people provided to those who had the same question, but none of them seem to work for me. I might be able to pull it off by using hacks, but I really don't want to do that. I feel like this is so simple, but I don't know how to fix it. So my question is: **what would be the best way to recreate this simple header?** How do I get the four navigation items to span the entire width of the container?

Apologies in advance if my question is too vague, I'm new to all of this.

Comment: but you already did it, no ? your code is like what you want

Comment: For one thing you'd have to remove any side padding on the header.

Comment: It looks fairly similar indeed, but it doesn't actually span the entire width of the container. I had to change the width of the ul li to 24%, otherwise the last link item positions itself beneath all the other link items. If you open up my code snippet in full page you'll see that there's some extra margin on the right side of the navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uee flexbox on the `ul`

```css
/* Reset */

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font: 1.6rem Arial;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Container */

#container {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  max-width: 96rem;
}


/* Header */

header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2.5rem;
  background: lightgrey;
}

header>.logo {
  /* Style */
  width: 12.5rem;
  height: 12.5rem;
  background: grey;
  /* Flex */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

header>nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header>nav ul li {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 .25em
}

header>nav ul li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

header>nav ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0
}

header>nav ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

header>nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>

    <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: and instead of width:24% i would use flex:1 and add some margin

Comment: I'd have to add margin to every single individual list item then, right? Because if I add a margin to the entire ul li, then it adds a bit of margin to the left side and right side of the unordered list as well... I'd like everything to line up perfectly

Comment: Amended to remove margins from 1st & Last `li`

Comment: Knew it had to be something simple. Thank you! I accepted this as my answer

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is how to make the items span the entire width of their container, `flex` can help you by adding this:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```